# NetSuite Queries and Proper Table Names

Tags: jquery, rest, postman, netsuite

I am trying to work with Oracle, NetSuite using Postman App (Mac) to get started with basic set up and queries.

I have the basics working, such as getting access and refresh tokens going and also basic queries from the Postman - netSuite rest API collection

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87118

Q: in the post man netSuite examples, these queries do work, however I am confused as to the table names, as they do not seem to match what is showing in the NetSuite Docs (ODBC)

https://zzzzz.app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/odbc/record/customer.html

they say:

FROM customer c, transaction t ????

why not : customers and transactions as table names? What is the significance  of customer 'c' and transaction 't' ? Am guessing correctly that the 'c' and the 't' are like alias for the table name to be used in the where area?

How can I find the proper table names to use for Rest API queries?

Any help would be appreciated– Dave

postman queries...

````
    "q": "SELECT c.email AS email, c.companyName AS company, t.tranId AS document, t.tranDate AS date FROM customer c, transaction t WHERE t.entity = c.id AND t.type = 'SalesOrd'"
}
// or
{
    "q": "SELECT id, companyName, email, dateCreated FROM customer WHERE dateCreated >= '{{thisYearStart}}' AND dateCreated < '{{thisYearEnd}}'"
}```
````

Comment: Use Setup -> Records Catalog in NetSuite to see the SuiteQL / Suite Analytics record names etc. The single letters (they can be larger if desired) are table aliases making it easier to reference fields without repeating the full table name for each.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the URL where you can see the table details of NetSuite

https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/odbc/record/customer.html

Comment: Thanks Much - These are for the odbc tables but I wonder if there is something different for the rest web services like [link]https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.1/index.html - I don't see anything for transaction_lines like we do in the odbc list?